# How to Save ONLY ONE face picture using OpenCV?

Tags: python, opencv, face-recognition

What am I trying to do?

1. Listen to camera video
2. Detect faces
3. Save only faces to folder

The problem:
I have done all of those things above EXCEPT it gives me bunch of same person faces because it checks it on every frame it captures and gives as new face when it's the same person.
I want the script to understand that it's the same person and skip it. (of course it depends on accuracy overall, but that's okay, as long as it's not giving me 60 files of same face a second)

So I was thinking to somehow use face_verify within the same library, but couldn't make it working quickly and decided to ask first instead of wasting time on something what most likely not gonna work.

Any suggestions? Hopefully described it well, also didn't find any duplicates of this question.
Thanks in advance

Comment: Aside from skipping frames (assuming this is live), could you do something like (also assuming you're getting a bounding box around the face), compare the new bounding box with the old bounding box, if the difference between the `x, y, w, h` values are too small, it's probably the same face? If the difference is large enough, probably a new face? Just spit balling... This also assumes there's no real facial recognition apart from object detection/classification...as in, classifying the actual person captured.

Answer (score 0):

It depends on what you are using, face-detection or face-recognition.

Face-detection will just detect faces and return bounding box for each frame. In this case you can use any simple tracking algorithm (like [SORT](https://github.com/abewley/sort)) which will give tracking ID for each bounding boxes in each frame. This way you can ensure to save only 1 face for each tracking ID

In case of Face-recognition, it's all the more easier as each detected face has an associated label (similar to a tracking ID in the above approach). So you can simply save face-images based on labels (1 image per label)

Comment: That's a nice idea, but means I will have to rewrite part of code. I'm currently using openCV with its xml files. but i understand now, there is a better ways to do it. Will try to discover. I guess the way i have done there is no way to provide ID for each face.

face_cascade = cv2.CascadeClassifier(cv2.data.haarcascades + "haarcascade_frontalface_default.xml") 
eye_cascade = cv2.CascadeClassifier(cv2.data.haarcascades + "haarcascade_eye.xml")